# Error in SELECT INTO Statement when trying to Merge multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till
INTO NBCVadodra
FROM
(SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power, total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I1]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I2]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I3]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I4]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I5]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I6]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I7]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I8]
UNION ALL
SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till FROM [dbo].[IN-023C-I9]
UNION ALL
)t
```

I wrote this query to combine the fields in all the tables to one table but it it throwing me an error in the first line of SELECT Tstamp, Inverter_id, AC_Power,total_energy_generated_till. When I execute I get an error saying "Incorrect syntax near ')' "

NBCVadodra is the new table that I need to insert the data to stack it up.

Comment: remove UNION ALL present before ')t'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line, there is no `SELECT` query after `UNION ALL`.This is where i think you are getting the error.